# How to change route name in .NET Odata?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have build some odata function in .NET.

Now each entity url like below:

http://1.1.1.1/APIName/odata/Products

I want to remove "/odata" words in the url. Like below:

http://1.1.1.1/APIName/Products

How to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

OK..I found the solution.

It worked as I wish after update setting as below.

```
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "", builder.GetEdmModel());
```